# How to add "standalone="yes" to XML declaration using xml.etree.ElementTree

Tags: python, xml, elementtree, xml-declaration

I've tried looking at other questions similar to this, but none seem to answer for xml.etree.ElementTree.

Currently my code looks like this (it's just a simple XML generator)

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

example1=ET.Element('example1')
example2=ET.SubElement(example1, 'example2').text='1234'
tree = ET.ElementTree(example1)
NewXML='example.xml'

tree.write(NewXML,encoding = 'UTF-8', xml_declaration = True)
```

Currently the output is simply this file:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<example1>
    <example2>1234</example2>
</example1>
```

I want to add the declaration standalone = 'yes' so the output should be:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone = 'yes'?>
<example1>
    <example2>1234</example2>
</example1>
```

However that's where I'm running into issues.

I've tried

```
tree.write(NewXML,encoding = "UTF-8", xml_declaration = True, standalone = True)
```

```
tree.write(NewXML,encoding = "UTF-8", xml_declaration = True, standalone = "yes")
```

but I get this error: TypeError: write() got an unexpected keyword argument 'standalone'

Comment: ElementTree does not have a `standalone` option on the `write()` method: https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.ElementTree.write. But lxml does: https://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree._ElementTree-class.html#write

Answer (score 3):

How about writing the declaration yourself?

```py
>>> import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
>>> example1=ET.Element('example1')
>>> example2=ET.SubElement(example1, 'example2').text='1234'
>>> tree = ET.ElementTree(example1)
>>> NewXML='example.xml'
>>> out = open(NewXML, 'wb')
>>> out.write(b'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone = "yes"?>\n')
58
>>> tree.write(out, encoding = 'UTF-8', xml_declaration = False)
>>> out.close()
>>>
```